# Getting Error while run function MD5

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

**My Function:**

```
DECLARE @Data varchar(50) = 'Rushang'
DECLARE @hash CHAR(32)
    set @data = 'Micro' + @data
EXEC master.dbo.xp_md5 @data, -1, @hash OUTPUT
select substring(@hash,5,17)
```

**Error:**

> Msg 17750, Level 16, State 0, Procedure xp_md5, Line 1
> Could not load the DLL xp_md5.dll, or one of the DLLs it references. Reason: 193(%1 is not a valid Win32 application.).
>
> (1 row(s) affected)
>
> Result:-
>
> NULL

Comment: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1018029-149-1.aspx just check this link you get an idea

Comment: @Mansoor please changes in my function and provide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FOR MD5 why not use 2008's built in HASHBYTES()?
```

DECLARE @IN  NVARCHAR(4000) = N'Hello' DECLARE @OUT VARBINARY(16) SET @OUT = HASHBYTES('MD5', @IN) SELECT @OUT